# Query to select date range from different columns

Tags: mysql, date-range

I have a `from_date` and `to_date` columns in my `LeaveApplication` table. So I'm trying to check if the specified date is in range of the two columns. For example:

**from_date** : 2021-08-26 
**to_date** : 2021-08-29 
**date** : 2021-08-27

I was trying to use the `BETWEEN` operator but the syntax is to select the date range from the same column name.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

In my case, I want to select the date range from different columns something like the query example below. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
SELECT * FROM LeaveApplication
WHERE "2021-08-27" BETWEEN (from_date = "2021-08-26") AND (to_date = "2021-08-29")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using greater, equal, and less operator didn't work for me but actually it can be done with `BETWEEN` operator this way

```
SELECT * FROM LeaveApplication WHERE "2021-08-27" BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
```

Found this example [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/sql/sql+check+if+date+is+between+2+dates)

p/s: my attempt in my example is quite close to it :)

Answer (score 0):

`select * from LeaveApplication where from_date >="2021-08-26" and to_date <="2021-08-26"`

If the result of rows is empty, the date exists, else not!

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confuse. Aren't the data will be displayed if the date is exist? Btw, I don't get any result. Tried with not in range date too and no result.

Comment: @EatenTaik The "select " is for select data content, so this SQL means you find the date between from_date  and to_date.  if the data is found, it means the "date" data between  from_date and to_date.

Comment: So you're saying if the date specified is between from_date and to_date, the result will be displayed? Cause in your comment you said that `If result is empty, the date exists`. In other words, if the date is exist, the data will not be displayed. Which is quite confusing.

Comment: @EatenTaik sorry for my poor English.  The SQL always gets result rows. if rows return empty, it is not between.